# Loop with .cget function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to change the "for i in range()"-value with a button.

the "cget" function doesn´t work. It gives me the following error: "*function' object cannot be interpreted as an integer*"

Does anyone have an idea on how to get this to work?

My not working code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
root = tk.Tk()


def test_btn_clicked():
    if test_btn.config('text')[-1] == '2'
        test_btn.config(text='5')

    else:
         test_btn.config(text='2')



test_btn = tk.Button(root, text="2", command=text_btn_clicked)
test_btn.pack()


def func1():
    for i in range(test_btn.cget('text')):
        sleep(5) 
        #do_something


test_func_btn = tk.Button(root, text="start", command=func1)
test_func_btn.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The result of `.cget('text')` is going to be a string - not something you can meaningfully pass to `range()`.  Apply `int()` to it to get an actual number.

Comment: That is what I got: `for i in range(test_btn.cget('text')):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`